# flutter image_web_picker Object? instead of Image returned

Tags: flutter, dart

I copied this from the official image web picker files but I get the message that getImage return an Object? instead of an Image. Where is the problem? And I importet the package if you think that is the problem.

```
class _LoadPhotoState extends State<LoadPhoto> {
  late final Image _pickedImage;

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    Image fromPicker = await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(outputType: ImageType.widget);
    setState(() {
      _pickedImage = fromPicker;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not your fault, the README is wrong: [the API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/image_picker_web/latest/image_picker_web/ImagePickerWeb/getImage.html) of that package says the `getImage` method returns a `Future<Object?>`. However, the solution is easy:

```dart
Image fromPicker = (await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(outputType: ImageType.widget)) as Image;
```